# Ignore hidden sheets when sum across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

could someone give me a hand with this I have this function to sum cells from multiple sheets. However I also have some hidden sheets that I don't want to be sum. How can I disable my function from reading the values from the cells in hidden sheets?
My code:

```
Function AutoSum(rng As Range) As Variant
    AutoSum = 0
    Application.Volatile True
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Application.ThisCell.Parent Then
            AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I have added this part `And ws.Visible = True`

```
Function AutoSum(rng As Range) As Variant
    AutoSum = 0
    Application.Volatile True
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Not ws Is Application.ThisCell.Parent And ws.Visible = True Then
            AutoSum = AutoSum + ws.Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```